# Why is the thing on Vito's cheek easily removed if it was a wound?

Tags: plot-explanation, family-business

In the 1989 movie, *Family Business*, Vito McMullen and his father Jessie are visiting a lawyer to help them in the case of Vito's son Adam.

Vito has a thing on his cheek in this scene.

When they go out of the office, Jessie looks at that thing and Vito tells him: "I have hurt my face with razor".

Then Jessie touches it and removes it from Vito's cheek.

If it was a wound caused by a razor then how was it easily removed? Sounds it was just a dirt on Vito's cheek to me.

[image: Vito]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He didn't remove the wound. He removed the tiny piece of toilet paper covering it which stopped it bleeding.

Using toilet paper on shaving cuts is a very old technique and largely unused today as more modern method of stopping the blood flow exist, but in a pinch it does work.

You do have to remember to remove the paper before you leave the house though.

Comment: And how is it attached to the skin?

Comment: @EtackSxchange: when the blood coagulates, it sticks to the skin. Old-fashioned barbers still have that special paper they use when making a tiny cut.